# Setup an autoconfig for IMAP/SMTP compatible with Windows Phone 8

Tags: settings, email

Is it possible to setup an autoconfig XML, such as [the one used for Thunderbird](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration#Configuration_file), which will work for Windows Phone 8?

This should be able to set the correct settings for IMAP and SMTP servers for the email account.

Comment: do you mean a configuration file at server level or to import on the phone?

Comment: At the server level, as it would be customers phones which would access this.